# Z3py: how to get the list of variables from a formula?

Tags: z3, z3py

In Z3Py, I have a formula. How can I retrieve the list of variables using in the formula?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vu Nguyen contributed several useful procedures to Z3Py.
He implemented a procedure `get_vars` to collect the list of used variables.
This procedure and many others can be found [here](http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/fbce8160252d#src/api/python/z3util.py).
His contributions will be available in the next official release.
Here is a version of `get_vars` that can be executed online at [rise4fun](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/bRhVN).

```py
# Wrapper for allowing Z3 ASTs to be stored into Python Hashtables. 
class AstRefKey:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
    def __hash__(self):
        return self.n.hash()
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.n.eq(other.n)
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.n)

def askey(n):
    assert isinstance(n, AstRef)
    return AstRefKey(n)

def get_vars(f):
    r = set()
    def collect(f):
      if is_const(f): 
          if f.decl().kind() == Z3_OP_UNINTERPRETED and not askey(f) in r:
              r.add(askey(f))
      else:
          for c in f.children():
              collect(c)
    collect(f)
    return r

x,y = Ints('x y') 
a,b = Bools('a b') 
print get_vars(Implies(And(x + y == 0, x*2 == 10),Or(a, Implies(a, b == False))))
```