# Z3py get_vars(f) equivalent for Java

Tags: java, z3

Following up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185826/whether-z3-java-bindings-has-the-get-vars-api-as-python-or-not) post: 
There is an example implementation how to get free variables with python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080398/z3py-how-to-get-the-list-of-variables-from-a-formula) which I wanted to re-implement in Java. How do I access the children of an Expr? I did not find a getter or visitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can visit subexpressions by recursing over the following three cases:

1. An expression can be a variable Expr.isVar()
2. An expression can be a quantifier Quantifier.isUniversal()/isExistential(), call getBody() to get child.
3. An expression can be an application, Expr.isApp(), use Expr.getArgs() to access the children.