# How to get the variable list from a z3 formula?

Tags: z3, z3py

I have a Z3 formula (in Z3py)

```
i=z3.Int('x')+z3.Int('y')<2
```

How can I get the variable list `x` and `y`?

Comment: See this [related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080398/z3py-how-to-get-the-list-of-variables-from-a-formula?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

I added an example to Z3 to illustrate walking subexpressions in Python.
https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/python/visitor.py